# Geometry question posed in RMO 1999

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $ ABCD $ be a square and  $ M, N $ points on sides $AB, BC $ respectively, such that  $\angle MDN = 45°$ . if $R$ is the midpoint of $MN$ show that $RP=RQ$ where $P,Q$ are the points of intersection of $AC$ with the lines $MD,ND$.
I have a feeling this problem can be solved by ***transformation geometry*** but since I'm new in this field, I have not proceeded a little. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a quite exceptional fact here: $P,Q,N,B,M$ all belong to the same circle with center $R$.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio So you suggest to prove that MNQP is concyclic?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $AMQD$ is cyclic with diameter $MD$ so $\angle QDM=\angle QMD=45^\circ$ thus $MQ\perp DN$.